# Generate multiple XHTML files form one XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, transformation

I would like to know if there is way to generate multiple xhtml files from one XML file via XSLT tranformation.
In XMl file are defined multiple slide tags for presentation.

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 and later you can use the `<xsl:result-document>` element. If you are limited to XSLT 1.0, you can still do it through an EXSLT extension (`<exsl:document>`). There is no way to do it in XSLT 1.0 without extensions.

Comment: @helderdarocha, that should be an answer not a comment.

Comment: You are right, @MichaelKay. I wasn't aware of that when I started the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

In **XSLT 2.0** and later you can use the `<xsl:result-document>` element. See [XSLT 2.0 #element-result-document](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document) and [Saxon: result-document](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/xsl-elements/result-document.html).

If you are limited to **XSLT 1.0**, you can still do it through an [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/) *extension* (`<exsl:document>`).

There is no way to do it in XSLT 1.0 without extensions.